# assign a procedure in a form to a notify event in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am trying to assign a procedure defined in the form to the event OnStateChange of the datasource like this:

```
unit SDIMAIN;

interface

uses Windows, ....., DB ;

type

  TSDIAppForm = class(TForm)
   ....
   procedure datasourceOnStateChange(Sender: TObject);

private
  stateChange : TNotifyEvent;
....

var
  SDIAppForm: TSDIAppForm;
...
end;

procedure TSDIAppForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 DataModule1.AdsTable1.Active := true;
 DataModule1.AdsTable2.Open;
stateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange(DataModule1.AdsTable1);
DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange := stateChange;

.
.
.
procedure TSDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin...end;
```

Initially when I tried doing the above I got the error! Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

```
I tried changing 
stateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange(DataModule1.AdsTable1); to
stateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange;

Now I don't get the error but it doesn't work. The OnStateChange event is not fired at all.

I tried with other methods like using

var
Method : TMethod;
.
.
.
Method.Data := Pointer(Self);
Method.Code := MethodAddress('datasourceOnStateChange'); and using pointers but it doesn't work.
```

I'm new to delphi and I'm currently learning. I might have not understood what exactly is supposed to be done. It would be really helpful if someone can help me on this problem.

```
Thanks.
```

Comment: Your second attempt should work (`stateChange:=SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange;` `DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange:=stateChange;`) as both of the answers point. If the handler is not called, it's not because the handler is not assigned.

Answer (score 4):

Assigning the Method `datasourceOnStateChange` to the Event of `DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange` will work:

```
   stateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange;
   DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange := stateChange;
```

which could be written as

```
DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange;
```

if you do not need `stateChange` for other purposes.

```
SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange(DataModule1.AdsTable1);
```

is a direct call of the method with `DataModule1.AdsTable1` as Sender, not the method it self.

Answer (score 2):

An event is simply a property whose type is a method.

You are trying to assign this event property. But instead of simply **assigning** the event handler to the property, you are **calling** the event handler. This code here contains the critical error:

```
SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange(DataModule1.AdsTable1)
```

This is a **call** of the event handler which you simply do not want to make. The component whose property refers to the event handler is the object that calls it.

I can guess how you made this mistake. When you started typing the name of the function, the IDE offered to auto-complete it for you. You accepted this help, but then the IDE dumbly assumed that you wanted to call the function and supplied parentheses for a function call. But you did not want to call the function, you wanted to take a reference to it. This is one of the more frustrating aspects of the IDE.

So, your code should be:

```
DataModule1.AdsTable1.Active := true;
DataModule1.AdsTable2.Open;
DataModule1.DataSource1.OnStateChange := SDIAppForm.datasourceOnStateChange;
```